# Stop parent event firing on child element click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a click event on `li` tag and then in that `li` i have another nested li.

When clicked on parent `li` everything works fine.  But onclick nested or child `li` the parent `li` click event is fired.

I have used `event.stopPropagation()` method but it does not work in my case.

```js
$("li").on("click",function() {
  console.log(this.firstChild.textContent)
})
$('#testUl > li').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="testUl">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test A</a>
    <div class="innerUl">
      <ul>
        <li>Inner A</li>
        <li>Inner B</li>
        <li>Inner C</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: $('#testUl > li') is probably the wrong selector. If you want the same function for parent and children: $('#testUI li')

Comment: Your code has the stopPropagation on the *parent* element.  Child elements get click events first.  This is assuming you have a *second* event on the child `li`, not included in your question.   Otherwise there's only a parent event anyway.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add YOUR function that you do not want executed

Comment: (note: 2nd event was added via edit, needs to be updated by OP, via an [edit])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without jQuery you can use [event delegation](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/) and determine to act using [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  console.clear();
  
  if (!evt.target.closest(`.innerUl`) && evt.target.closest(`#testUl`)) {
      console.log(`You clicked (something within) the first li of ul#testUl`);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="testUl">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test A</a>
    <div class="innerUl">
      <ul>
        <li>Inner A</li>
        <li>Inner B</li>
        <li>Inner C</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Same idea with jQuery

```js
$("#testUl").on("click", evt => {
    console.clear();
    if (!evt.target.closest(`.innerUl`) && evt.target.closest(`#testUl`)) {
      console.log(`You clicked ${evt.target.outerHTML}`);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script 
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<ul id="testUl">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test A</a>
    <div class="innerUl">
      <ul>
        <li>Inner A</li>
        <li>Inner B</li>
        <li>Inner C</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works fine, but is will called in every click on page?

Comment: @naxsi yes, but that's not really a problem. Nothing happens if the condition is not met.

Comment: From [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) "*Second, the delegation may add CPU load, because the container-level handler reacts on events in any place of the container, no matter whether they interest us or not. But usually the load is negligible, so we don’t take it into account.*". The second example (jQuery) only monitors clicks on `ul#testUl` btw.

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('#testUl .innerUl li').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

// or 
$('#testUl li').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('#testUl > li').on('click', function(e) {
   alert('test');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- #testUl -->
<ul id="testUl">
    <!-- #testUl > li -->
    <li>
        <!-- #testUl > li > a or #testUl a -->
        <a href="#">Test A</a>
        <!-- #testUl > li > .innerUl or #testUl .innerUl -->
        <div class="innerUl">
            <!-- #testUl > li > .innerUl > ul or #testUl ul -->
            <ul>
                <!-- #testUl > li > .innerUl > ul > li or #testUl li or #testUl .innerUl li or .innerUl li -->
                <li>Inner A</li>
                <li>Inner B</li>
                <li>Inner C</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You are using a wrong selector for stop propagation

When you use `#testUl > li` you call the first  `li`  child element, but you have `li` elements inside your `li` on `#testUl`, so call `#testUl li` or `#testUl .innerUl li`

Answer (score 2):

You can compare `e.target` which is element that have `click` event and `e.currentTarget` that is element you actually clicked. If they don't match then you return without performing rest of function

```js
$('#testUl > li').on('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        return;
    }
    console.log('parent');
});

$('.innerUl li').on('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        return;
    }
    console.log('child');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="testUl">
    <li>
        Test A
        <div class="innerUl">
            <ul>
                <li>Inner A</li>
                <li>Inner B</li>
                <li>Inner C</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `stopImmediatePropagation()`

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation